# Site farm server with multiple users - best aproach

Tags: centos, hosting, static-content

I am buliding kind a hosting server for static sites, and i am wondering is it better and for what reasons to:

1) use linux users ( i dont need ssh or something advanced function, there is only static content

2) use one linux user and application logic for spliting user sites on front end app.

I am interesed in unnessesery overhead, overkill, resources consuming etc.

server used is ngnix, and application will be node.js